# Spring Interview Questions required

Tags: spring

I am looking for an extensive list of Spring Interview questions? I have searched developerBooks and some others too, but havent found an extensive list.

Any Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring certification study guide can be a reasonable source of questions http://www.springsource.com/files/core-spring-3.0-certification-study-guide.pdf

Comment: And also http://www.developersbook.com/spring/interview-questions/spring-interview-questions-faqs.php

Comment: you can check latest interview questions at http://modernpathshala.com/Article/1024/top-spring-interview-questions-and-answers-part-1